# Set any param in PreparedStatement not working

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, resultset

I have a SQL request defined like that :

```
private static final String fetchOfferQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT "
        + "sim_id, sim_code, sim_label, sim_state, sim_type, sim_customerid, sim_storeid, sim_projectnumber, sim_version, sim_type_user, sim_type_vente, sim_statut, "
        + "(SELECT MAX(set_date) FROM offer_storage.t_simulationeventtrack_set WHERE set_sim_id = sim_id) AS sim_dateevtmax, "
        + "sim_creation_user, sim_modif_user, sim_rayon, sim_hours_lifetime, sim_eligible_reduced_vat, sim_store_linked, sim_canal, "
        + "ofr_id, CAST(ofr_creationdate AS timestamp) AS ofr_creationdate, ofr_label, ofr_state, ofr_transaction, ofr_modif_date, ofr_del_valid, "
        + "ofr_numcdecli, "
        + "ofi_id, ofi_productid, ofi_quantity,ofi_productprice, ofi_top, ofi_c1promo, ofi_codeactivite, ofi_codrem, "
        + "ofi_datejour, ofi_datepose, ofi_dateprevpose, ofi_datfinc1, ofi_datfinprxvtepromo, ofi_delai, ofi_libligdtl, ofi_montantpresta, "
        + "ofi_montrt, ofi_aro_id, ofi_numartisan, ofi_prxvte, ofi_prxvtepromo, ofi_typinitialoff, ofi_typoff, ofi_c1, ofi_numlig, "
        + "deo_id, deo_numligdtl, deo_codligdtl, deo_libligdtl, "
        + "aro_id, aro_type_offer, aro_type_inioff, aro_top_caisse, aro_num_arty, aro_date_prev, aro_mntrt, aro_date_jour, "
        + "aro_delai, aro_mnt_presta, aro_codact, aro_date_pose "
        + "FROM offer_storage.t_simulation_sim "
        //with fixed date
        + "INNER JOIN offer_storage.t_simulationeventtrack_set ON set_sim_id = sim_id AND set_date >= TO_DATE('20180726000000','yyyymmddhh24miss') "
        //with bind parameter
        //+ "INNER JOIN offer_storage.t_simulationeventtrack_set ON set_sim_id = sim_id AND set_date >= ?  "
        + "LEFT JOIN offer_storage.t_offer_ofr ON ofr_sim_id = sim_id "
        + "LEFT JOIN offer_storage.t_offeritem_ofi ON ofi_ofr_id = ofr_id "
        + "LEFT JOIN offer_storage.t_details_item_offer_deo ON deo_ofi_id = ofi_id "
        + "LEFT JOIN offer_storage.t_artisan_offer_aro ON aro_id = ofi_aro_id "
        + "ORDER BY sim_id, ofr_id, ofi_id, deo_id, aro_id";
```

If I set a fixed date in the request :

```
...
            + "INNER JOIN offer_storage.t_simulationeventtrack_set ON set_sim_id = sim_id AND set_date >= TO_DATE('20180726000000','yyyymmddhh24miss') "
        ...
```

And play the request with : 
simulationsSt = connection.prepareStatement(fetchOfferQuery);
ResultSet simulationsRs = simulationsSt.executeQuery();

The request take 1min30 to end.

If I use the bind parameter :

```
        ...
        + "INNER JOIN offer_storage.t_simulationeventtrack_set ON set_sim_id = sim_id AND set_date >= ?  "
        ...
```

With set method before executeQuery (dateLastExtract = same Date of 20180726000000) :

```
        simulationsSt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(this.dateLastExtract.getTime()));
```

The request take 10min !

I also have the problem with all requests I need to set any param (int, date, string...etc).
So it's not specific to date, it's just when I use binding and when I'm not.

For information, the number of data rows are pretty huge :

```
t_simulationeventtrack_set : 66.097.939 rows    
t_details_item_offer_deo : 46.259.704 rows    
t_offeritem_ofi : 14.232.150 rows    
t_artisan_offer_aro : 2.317.658 rows    
t_offer_ofr : 1.801.969 rows    
t_simulation_sim : 1.756.235 rows
```

The CREATE TABLE t_simulationeventtrack_set script is :

```
CREATE TABLE "OFFER_STORAGE"."T_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SET" 
   (    "SET_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SET_DATE" DATE, 
    "SET_CHANGETYPE" VARCHAR2(254 BYTE), 
    "SET_CHANGE" VARCHAR2(254 BYTE), 
    "SET_USR_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "SET_SIM_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK" PRIMARY KEY ("SET_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OAA_INDX"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OAA_DATA" ;

  CREATE INDEX "OFFER_STORAGE"."IDX_SET_SIM_ID" ON "OFFER_STORAGE"."T_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SET" ("SET_SIM_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OAA_INDX" ;

  CREATE INDEX "OFFER_STORAGE"."IDX_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_DATE" ON "OFFER_STORAGE"."T_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SET" ("SET_DATE") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OAA_INDX" ;

  CREATE INDEX "OFFER_STORAGE"."IDX_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_FDATE" ON "OFFER_STORAGE"."T_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SET" (TO_CHAR("SET_DATE",'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OAA_INDX" ;

  CREATE INDEX "OFFER_STORAGE"."IDX_SIM_ID_USER_ID" ON "OFFER_STORAGE"."T_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SET" ("SET_SIM_ID", "SET_USR_ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "OAA_INDX" ;
```

What is wrong ?

I've tried to add an index on "T_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SET" ("SET_SIM_ID", "SET_DATE")
But it didn't change anything.

EDIT :

I've find a solution for the date param here : 
https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/22/are-you-binding-your-oracle-dates-correctly-i-bet-you-arent/

If I used "CAST(? AS DATE)" in replacement of "?", it works fast !

But now I have the same problem with an integer param.
I've a clause ">= CAST(? AS DATE) OR 1 = ?"
The second param is 1 or 0, and if I put 0, it gonna take every line even the old one.

When I put this simple int param, it is slow again...

**EDIT 2 :**

Here is the execution plan with binding :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                             |       |       |       |   191M(100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE              |                             |     1 |    14 |       |            |          |
|   2 |   FIRST ROW                  |                             |     1 |    14 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)| IDX_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SD |     1 |    14 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |  SORT ORDER BY               |                             |    26 |  9698 |    17G|   191M  (1)|637:07:31 |
|   5 |   FILTER                     |                             |       |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER     |                             |    46M|    16G|  3351M|   915K  (1)| 03:03:10 |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL        | T_DETAILS_ITEM_OFFER_DEO    |    46M|  2815M|       |   145K  (1)| 00:29:01 |
|   8 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER    |                             |    14M|  4263M|   134M|   384K  (1)| 01:16:57 |
|   9 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL       | T_ARTISAN_OFFER_ARO         |  2317K|   108M|       |  4543   (1)| 00:00:55 |
|  10 |      HASH JOIN OUTER         |                             |    14M|  3589M|   325M|   187K  (1)| 00:37:28 |
|  11 |       HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER  |                             |  1823K|   304M|   125M| 35194   (1)| 00:07:03 |
|  12 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL     | T_OFFER_OFR                 |  1824K|   104M|       |  5995   (1)| 00:01:12 |
|  13 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL     | T_SIMULATION_SIM            |  1778K|   195M|       | 12293   (1)| 00:02:28 |
|  14 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL      | T_OFFERITEM_OFI             |    14M|  1183M|       | 69005   (1)| 00:13:49 |
|  15 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SD |     1 |    14 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_SET_SIM_ID              |     2 |    12 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the execution plan without binding (more faster) :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                          | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                               |       |       |       |   163K(100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                     |                               |     1 |    14 |       |            |          |
|   2 |   FIRST ROW                         |                               |     1 |    14 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)       | IDX_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SD   |     1 |    14 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |  SORT ORDER BY                      |                               |   156K|    57M|    60M|   163K  (1)| 00:32:41 |
|   5 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                |                               |   156K|    57M|       |   150K  (1)| 00:30:07 |
|   6 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER               |                               | 48049 |    14M|       | 40080   (1)| 00:08:01 |
|   7 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                               | 48049 |    12M|       | 35935   (1)| 00:07:12 |
|   8 |      HASH JOIN OUTER                |                               |  6085 |  1123K|       | 12654   (1)| 00:02:32 |
|   9 |       NESTED LOOPS                  |                               |       |       |       |            |          |
|  10 |        NESTED LOOPS                 |                               |  5930 |   747K|       |  6654   (1)| 00:01:20 |
|  11 |         SORT UNIQUE                 |                               |  6008 | 84112 |       |   643   (0)| 00:00:08 |
|  12 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SET    |  6008 | 84112 |       |   643   (0)| 00:00:08 |
|  13 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_DATE |  6008 |       |       |    20   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_SIMULATION                 |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | T_SIMULATION_SIM              |     1 |   115 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL             | T_OFFER_OFR                   |  1779K|   101M|       |  5994   (1)| 00:01:12 |
|  17 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | T_OFFERITEM_OFI               |     8 |   688 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN              | IDX_OFI_OFR_ID                |     9 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | T_ARTISAN_OFFER_ARO           |     1 |    49 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | PK_ARTISANOFFER               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | T_DETAILS_ITEM_OFFER_DEO      |     3 |   189 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IDX_DEO_OFI_ID                |    22 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have two parameters you should be binding values to both of them.

Comment: I make a mistake posting the code, I only have one parameter ;) 
I just upated my original post.
Did you have an idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is it hanging on the `setInt()` call, or is it getting past that and hanging on the `executeQuery()` call? Does it still hang if you revert to the parameter version after running one of the others? Have you looked at the execution plans for the direct and parameterised queries?

Comment: It is hanging on executeQuery call, the setInt is ok.

Comment: attr-host-variable must be a string host variable and the content must conform to the rules for attribute-string. The ATTRIBUTES clause can only be specified before variable.

Comment: There are some rules of creating dynamic query using prepared statement please check this. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_prepare.html

Comment: And this is well deserved question to be answer by some expert.

Comment: What do you mean ? I don't understand nothing about attribute-string rules... You mean that I can't make param replacement here at the end of the request ?

For information, these param replacement works when I launch the code on the server, but not in local...

Comment: I just found that on IBM forum, that Param key should be in string and you taking it as 1=? Instead we should have string=?, correct me If i am wrong

Comment: Ok.
Weird because it works on the server.
And also, I have the problem with an other request with only a date param which use a variable like you said.

Comment: Then try setting another Param without having 1=? In your query

Comment: I made a test with the date param, not working eather...
I'm gonna update the original post to add this code

Comment: FInally it works but take 2min longer than putting direcly the Date in the request. Is that a difference between putting a "date_field >= TO_DATE(...) " and "date_field >= ?" with a .setTimestamp ?

Comment: I totally update the original post to expose the actual situation. I've added a lot of details also. Hope you could help. Thanks

Comment: I posted the execution plan, if you've a clue, I'll be really interested... Thank you

Answer (score 4):

When two copies of essentially the same query have very different performance characteristics, the cause is usually some quirk in how the execution plan is calculated by the optimizer.

For the above, I will note that your query has a Cartesian join.  As per the Oracle documentation concerning
[Cartesian Joins](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_join.htm#TGSQL94986) :
"In some cases, the optimizer could pick up a common filter condition between the two tables as a possible join condition."

One possible cause of the apparent choice of a not optimal execution plan may be the presence of the bind variables - see the Oracle documentation on [Why Execution Plans Change](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_genplan.htm#TGSQL94696) :
"Some factors that affect the costs include the following:
...
Bind variable types and values
..."

One interpretation of the statements from the Oracle documentation is 'if you specify a Cartesian join, you may require some luck to have it perform well - and using bind variables does not improve your chances'.

If you update the query by replacing **"FROM t_user_usr, t_simulationeventtrack_set "**
with **"FROM t_user_usr INNER JOIN t_simulationeventtrack_set ON xxx=yyy "** 
(xxx=yyy should probably be one of the conditions in the WHERE, but it is not possible to tell which one without the table description) would likely make the optimizer behave better.

The first question had the statement 'The request is launched, but it never end, no error is displayed.'  How long was 'never' in this instance?  I ask because, when something should take a fraction of a second anything approaching the 30 seconds mark may well find itself killed on my machine.

The latest problem with '... OR 1 = ?' will force the execution plan for the query to not use the SIM_ID + SET_DATE index (which, given the data size, will produce a performance issue).
Given what the condition does, I would simply have 2 prepared statements in my Java code (one with and one without the date condition) - that should allow the optimizer to pick the correct index to use for each of these.

Comment: In fact, I have another request with the same problem, and there is no cartesian join, only "left join", and the problem is the same. I'm gonna add this second request in the original post.

Comment: Could you share what the result was for the proposed change in the above with the previous issue?  Next, if you have the same problem, you would then also have the timings for both bind and non-bind execution of the query.  Providing that would also be nice.  As a third point - could you provide the SHOW CREATE TABLE details for the tables involved (this should have been raised before)?

Comment: I added the create table details for the table which have problems I think (because it contains millions of lines).

Comment: You may wish to also add 'CREATE INDEX MYCOMBO ON "OFFER_STORAGE"."T_SIMULATIONEVENTTRACK_SET" ("SET_SIM_ID", "SET_DATE")  as most of the conditions refer to both columns.  Please note that getting the numbers would still be nice.

Comment: I totally update the original post to expose the actual situation. I've added a lot of details also. Hope you could help. Thanks

Comment: I posted the execution plan, if you've a clue, I'll be really interested... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the SQL engine eliminates constant expressions like `X OR 1=0` to `X`.
And for a dynamic prepared expression not so, failing to use some index on `set_date`.

The condition has the purpose to disable the filtering on `set_date`, going for all `set_date` values.

If feasible you could do that by replacing

```
        + "AND (set_date >= TO_DATE('2018-07-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD') "
        + "OR 1 = ?) "
```

with

```
        + "AND set_date >= ? "
```

and

```
       LocalDate d = seen == 1 ? LocalDate.of(1900, 1, 1) : LocalDate.of(2018, 7, 19);
       java.sql.Date sd = new java.sql.Date(d.toEpochDay);
       simulationsSt.setDate(1, sd);
```

Comment: I totally update the original post to expose the actual situation. I've added a lot of details also. Hope you could help. Thanks

Comment: Okay it seems you need a non-unique index on SET_DATE. An index of (SIM_ID, SET_DATE) is useless certainly if SIM_ID is the (unique) primary key. Maybe fastest would be (SET_DATE, SIM_ID) for the reordering of ORDER_BY. Try it in the WHERE part i.o. INNER JOIN AND. _(I might well be mistaken about which table SET_DATE belongs to.)_

Comment: Thank you. I don't all understand, what do you want to try ? I've just updated the original post again, I've find a solution putting CAST(? AS DATE) in the request, but it's not really "clean" and I've now the same problem with the int param.

Comment: Miscommunication. I commented that there is no index on SET_DATE. You tried on the combined key SET_SIM_ID+SET_DATE and maybe SET_DATE+SET_SIM_ID might be faster. Casts and other patches" should not be needed with a PreparedStatement. setDate for java.sql.Date+DATE, and setTimestamp for Timestamp+DATETIME/TIMESTAMP.

Comment: When I use a : java.sql.Date tmstpExtract = new java.sql.Date(this.dateLastExtract.getTime()); and setDate, in place of Timestamp tmstpExtract = new Timestamp(this.dateLastExtract.getTime()); and setTimestamp, it also works quickly. But I don't understand why... Timestamp in java and SQL are the same format no ?

Comment: java.util.Date is day+time. SQL DATE = day = java.sql.Date (extends java.util.Date but zeroes time part). SQL TIMESTAMP/DATETIMe = day+time = java.sql.Timestamp (extend java.util.date, just other name). A driver will normally convert setInt/setDouble/setDate/setTimestamp to some degree, but `setDate` will loose its time part for a TIMESTAMP field.

Comment: I posted the execution plan, if you've a clue, I'll be really interested... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The request is launched, but it never end, no error is displayed.

when you have a long running statement (more than a few seconds), you can see it in v$session_longops

```
select * from v$session_longops v order by v.start_time desc;
```

Find it, take the sql_id and look up the statement in dba_hist_sqltext

```
select * from dba_hist_sqltext t where t.sql_id = 'b6usrg82hwsa3';
```

and its execution plan in dba_hist_sql_plan:

```
select * from dba_hist_sql_plan p where p.sql_id = 'b6usrg82hwsa3' order by p.plan_hash_value, p.id;
```

you might get more than 1 here (different plan_hash_value).

As Joop Eggen already posted, you're probably running into a different execution plan when you actually set the parameters via bind variables.

Comment: I totally update the original post to expose the actual situation. I've added a lot of details also. Hope you could help. I'm gonna try to add the execution plan but it's difficult to post it here because it is not well formated with the request.

Comment: there is no need to post the execution plans if you can spot the difference yourself. If you have incorrect data binding like in your case the date type, then you'll notice that the search_column differ between the 2 queries. For example: you can't use an index on a date column if you query with a timestamp parameter, because oracle needs to cast each and every date to timestamp to compare it.

Comment: I posted the execution plan, if you've a clue, I'll be really interested... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the faster execution plan, the index on the date column is used and it's where the optimizer starts. In the slower execution plan, the optimizer doesn't notice that this is a good index, so he starts somewhere else.

The problem is that java.sql.Timestamp Data Type does not correspond to oracle DATE.
"set_date" is of type DATE, that means it's stored with a precision of seconds. Now you make a query with a parameter that is of type java.sql.Timestamp which has nanosecond precision. In order to compare the DATE values in the table with the query parameter, oracle has to use a function to transform DATE into a higher precision (think of it as a cast in java). And unfortunately, indexes don't work if you first need to use a function on the column's value.

What you should do: When querying through JDBC, always use lower precision temporal types than the type of the column. In your case: Either use java.sql.Date for the query or change the data type of the column to at least nanosecond precision.

I know this doesn't solve your problem with other data types, but that's all I can tell you from the info and execution plans you posted.